# Isolation Lemma over finite fields

Tags: pr.probability

i couldn't find the answer to the following question:

The [Isolation Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_lemma) of Mulmuley, Vazirani and Vazirani uses the weight function $w:[n] \rightarrow [m]$ and assigns a subset $S \subseteq [n]$ the weight $w(S) = \sum_{x\in S} w(x)$, for $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, where $w(x)$ are randomly chosen. The statement of the Lemma is, that for a family of subsets $S_i$ there is a subset $S_j$ that has a minimum weight and with probability $> 1-\frac{n}{m}$ it is unique. (Here $[n] := [1,...,n]$)

Is some generalization of the Isolation Lemma valid if the weight function maps to a Finite Field or even a Ring? For example if the weight function is changed to $w:[n] \rightarrow GF(2^q)$ or $w:[n] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_M$ for some integer $M$. Note that also the weight $w(S)$ of a subset is mapped to the Finite Field (or Ring).  In this case there the notion of the "minimum weight" set is not well-defined because the elements of a field or ring are not ordered.

But are there conditions under which, say, there is at most one *zero-sum* subset with probability $> 1-\frac{n}{m}$?

Regards,
Etsch

Comment: Finite fields or rings cannot be ordered. So how do you define *minimal*?

Comment: Also, the URL is broken.

Comment: Thx, i removed the link for now. Your comment i correct, i will rephrase the question - thx

Comment: In general the answer to this is no.  The Isolation Lemma holds even if all $2^n$ subsets are in the family, but in this case the average number of sets of a given weight is $2^n/m$.  Consider the case when all $2^n$ sets are present and $w:[n]\to\mathbb Z_m$ with addition mod $m$.  If the weights are randomly chosen as described, then by symmetry the expected number of weight-zero sets is $1+(2^n-1)/m$.  Surely this number exceeds one probability more than $1-n/m$?  (Will think about it.)

Comment: Yes, this is right Neal, i came up with something similar. I dont think the Isolation Lemma can be extendet this way. Maybe because i am still dont know how to define mimimal as Emil has noted - except focusing directly on the zero-sum subset. Thx

Comment: Why not just take an arbitrary total order over the finite field and require the weight to be the minimal with respect to that order? Neal's argument would still give a counterexample if the finite field is small, but if it is larger than $2^n$, maybe the lemma might work?

Comment: @OrMeir The original isolation lemma over $\mathbb Z$ does not work if you replace the standard order with an arbitrary order; it essentially relies on the fact that addition is increasing. Why would you expect the case of finite fields to be any better?

Comment: I added an answer that shows that as long as $\log m \ll n$ there is no hope --- all sets will have exponentially many sets with the same weight.  In the case that $m \gg 2^{2n}$, with high probability *every* set will a unique weight (this is essentially the birthday paradox).  In the intermediate case $2^n \ll m \ll 2^{2n}$ many but not all sets will have unique weights, so there are certainly pre-determined rules that will select such a set... maybe the minimum-weight set is one?

Comment: But if $m \ge 2^n$, instead of taking each weight $w(i)$ to be random, why not just take $w(i) = 2^{i-1}$?  This guarantees that each set will have a unique weight.  Maybe, to go any further with this inquiry, we would need to know more about the context / motivation.

Comment: Yes, with probability at least $1-\frac{3^n}m$ or so, the weights of all the sets will be pairwise different, and this holds over any ring. however, this is an exponentially worse bound than the actual isolation lemma, and I doubt it is useful for similar purposes.

Comment: The case $m \geq 2^n$ is indeed not of interest. But the idea to take $w(i) = 2^{i-1}$ is actually a nice idea of independent interest. I am still reading the answers below, they look promising. Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an alternative (and, hopefully, simpler) proof of Neal Young’s argument. To simplify the presentation, I take the set $\def\S{\mathcal S}\S$ of all $2^n-1$ *nonempty* subsets of $[n]$, and a uniformly random weight $w\colon[n]\to\def\z#1{\mathbb Z/#1\mathbb Z}\z m$ (the argument actually works for any abelian group of size $m$ just the same). I will prove

> **Theorem:** With probability at least $1-4m^22^{-n}$, every weight in $\z m$ is attained by at least $\frac{2^n}{2m}$ sets.

For any $a\in\z m$, let $W_a$ denote the random variable
$$\bigl|\{S\in\S:w(S)=a\}\bigr|,$$
and for $S\in\S$, let $W_{a,S}\in\{0,1\}$ be the indicator of $w(S)=a$, so that
$$W_a=\sum_{S\in\S}W_{a,S}.$$
By fixing $w$ for all but one element of $S$, we see that
$\DeclareMathOperator\E{E}\E W_{a,S}=\frac1m$, hence
$$\E W_a=\frac{2^n-1}m.$$
Moreover, for fixed $a$, the variables $\{W_{a,S}:S\in\S\}$ are pairwise independent: given $S\ne S'$, fix (wlog) $i\in S'\let\bez\smallsetminus\bez S$. Then $w(S)$ is determined by $w\restriction([n]\bez\{i\})$, and it is $a$ with probability $1/m$, while conditioned on any fixed choice of $w\restriction([n]\bez\{i\})$, $w(S')=a$ with probability $1/m$. Thus,
$$\DeclareMathOperator\var{var}\var W_a=\sum_{S\in\S}\var W_{a,S}=\frac{2^n-1}m\left(1-\frac1m\right).$$
By Chebyshev’s inequality,
$$\Pr\left[W_a\le(2^n-1)\left(\frac1m-\delta\right)\right]\le\frac{\var W_a}{(2^n-1)^2\delta^2}=\frac{1-1/m}{(2^n-1)\delta^2m}\le\frac1{2^n\delta^2m}$$
as long as $m\le2^n$ (which we may assume as otherwise the statement of the theorem holds vacuously). By the union bound,
$$\Pr\left[\forall a\in\z m\:W_a>(2^n-1)\left(\frac1m-\delta\right)\right]\ge1-\frac1{2^n\delta^2}.$$
Taking $\delta=1/(2m)$ gives the theorem.

Comment: Oh, very nice...  FYI this variance bound can replace the use of Lemma 1 in the proof I gave, giving a tighter bound, but I think that even with that modification the bound that proof gives isn't as good as the bound your simpler proof gives.

Comment: All right, thank you.

Comment: Thx Emil, i marked your answer as correct, since the proof is more comprehensible. Also thx to Neal for the first one.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a counter-example showing that at least when $\log m \ll n$ isolation is not possible: with high probability, *every* weight has exponentially many sets summing to it, so no particular set is "isolated" by its weight.  (The example still leaves open the possibility that, say, the minimum-weight set could be likely to be isolated in the case that, say, $m \gg 2^n$.)

Take the set family to be all $2^n$ subsets of $[n]$.  Take the weights to be in $\mathbb Z_m$ with addition mod $m$. (Typically one would take, say, $m=n^2$.)  Let the element weights $w(x)$ $(x\in [n])$ be selected independently and uniformly at random from $\mathbb Z_m$.  Recall that the weight of a given set $S\subseteq [n]$ is defined to be $w(S) = (\sum_{x\in S} w(x))\bmod m$.

**Theorem 1.** *For every $k\ge 0$, with probability at least $1 - 1/2^k$, every weight $x$ in $\mathbb Z_m$
has at least $2^{n - O(k\log m)}$ sets $S$ with weight $w(S)=x$.*

(No doubt the probability bound can be improved.)

*Proof.* For $t\ge 0$ and $x\in\mathbb Z_m$, define $C(t, x) = |\{S\subseteq [t] : w(S) = x\}|$ to be the number of weight-$x$ subsets of the first $t$ elements.
So $C(0,0)=1$ (for the empty set), $C(0, x) = 0$ for $x\ne 0$,
and for $t\ge 1$ and $x\in\mathbb Z_m$
$$C(t, x) = C(t-1, x) + C(t-1, x -_m w(t)),\hspace{1in}(1)\hspace{-1in}$$
where $-_m$ denotes subtraction mod $m$.

Define $m_t = |\{x\in\mathbb Z_m : C(t, x) \ge 1\}|$ to be the number of distinct set weights achieved by the end of round $t$. Let r.v. $T$ be the number of rounds until $m_T = m$, that is, $C(t, x)\ge 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb Z_m$.
(Technically, in this definition we are imagining that the random experiment goes on indefinitely---more than $n$ rounds---adding a new random weight each time.)

**Lemma 1.** $E[T] \le 1+3\ln m$

*Proof of Lemma 1.*  By (1), in each round $t \le T$, any given weight $x\not\in W_{t-1}$ enters $W_t$ if $x\in w(t) +_m W_{t-1}$, that is, $x -_m w(t) \in W_{t-1}$,
which (given that $w(t)$ is random, so $x -_m w(t)$ is random, and $|W_{t-1}|=m_{t-1}$) happens with probability $m_{t-1}/m$.  It follows that
$$\textstyle
E[m_t - m_{t-1} \,|\, m_{t-1}=i] = (m-m_{t-1})\frac{m_{t-1}}{m} = \frac{1}{1/m_{t-1} + 1/(m-m_{t-1})}.\hspace{.6in}(2)\hspace{-.6in}
$$

For $j\le m$ define
$\textstyle F(j) =  \sum_{i=1}^j \frac{2}{i} + \frac{1}{\max(m-i, 1)}.$

Using the definition of $F$ and $m_{t-1} \le m_t \le 2 m_{t-1}$, we have $F(m_t)-F(m_{t-1})$ is at most
$$\textstyle
 \sum_{i=m_{t-1}+1}^{m_{t}} \frac{2}{i} + \frac{1}{\max(m-i, 1)}
\ge
 (m_{t} - m_{t-1})(\frac{2}{m_{t}} + \frac{1}{m-m_{t-1}}
\ge
 (m_{t} - m_{t-1})(\frac{1}{m_{t-1}} + \frac{1}{m-m_{t-1}}),
$$
which with (2) implies $E[F(m_t)-F(m_{t-1}) \,|\, m_{t-1}] \ge 1$.
By Wald's equation, $$E[F(m_T)] \ge F(m_0) + E[T] = E[T].$$

This implies $E[T] \le E[F(m_T)] = F(m)$.

By calculation $F(m) = 2 H_m + H_{m-1} + 1 \le 1+3\ln m$.$~~~~\Box$

Let $B = 2+6\ln m$.
By Lemma 1 and the Markov bound, the probability of the "bad" event $T \ge B$ is at most $1/2$.
So, with probability at least $1/2$, the sets $S\subseteq [B]$ generate all $m$ weights.
By applying the same argument to the sets $S\subseteq \{B+1,B+2,\ldots, 2B\}$, with probability at least $1/2$, those sets generate all $m$ weights.
Likewise, partitioning the first $k B$ indices (in $[kB]$) into $k$ groups of size $B$,
each group of sets generates all weights with probability at least $1/2$,
so (using independence of the groups) the probability of the bad event that none of the group's sets generates all the weights is at most $1/2^k$.
Assume this bad event does not happen.
Then, at the start of round $t_0=kB$,
we have $\min_x C(t, x) \ge 1 = 2^0$ for all $x$.

Then at the end of each round $t\ge t_0$, recalling (1), we have $$\min_x C(t, x) \ge 2\min_{x'} C(t-1, x'),$$
so inductively $\min_x C(t, x) \ge 2^{t-t_0}$.
So, by the final round $t=n$ we have
$$\min_x C(n, x) \ge 2^{n-t_0} = 2^{n-kB} = 2^{n-O(k \log m)}.~~~~~\Box$$